# Porque algunas pc de mi red no pueden acceder a una api publicafa desde el iis de mi maquina

Tags: api, asp, iis

Hola buenos días Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer el llamado a una api que esta ejecutándose en mi iss
Es decir yo soy el servidor y los demás usuarios de la red debería poder verlo
Pero de las 6 pc solo 2 aparte de mi puede ver la api.
Porque las otras maquinas no puede hacerlo?
Alguien se ha topado con este problema?
De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Qué error ven esos usuarios? Cómo es la arqutectura de red de tu solución? Están todos en el mismo segmento de red? Esta pregunta exige más adivinación de la cuenta. Amplíala, por favor

Comment: Como tal solo dice que tardo demasiado en responder: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, Todos los usuarios estamos en la misma red, por eso unos si pueden acceder pero otros no y se la arquitectura mvc